# adding item to the end of linked list segfault

Tags: c

```
struct vehicle *add_vehicle(struct vehicle *v){

    struct vehicle *newcar = (struct vehicle*)malloc(sizeof(struct 
    vehicle));
    scanf("%s", newcar->regnro);
    scanf("%s", newcar->model);
    newcar->next = NULL;
   if(v->next == NULL){
      v->next =newcar;
  }
   else{
       struct vehicle *current = v;
       while(current->next != NULL){
           current = current->next;
           }
         current->next = newcar;
         }
 return v; 
       }
```

I am trying to add vehicle to end of the list but it gives me Segmentation fault after second scanf, I dont know is my mistake in loops or in scanf. My struct is like:

```
    struct vehicle {
    char regnro[7];
    char *model;
    struct vehicle *next;
};
```

Comment: `newcar->model` is uninitialized. You need to malloc space for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly as pointed by other in comments `model` is pointer member of structure & its not initialzed. When you do `scanf("%s", newcar->model);` it gives seg. fault. So first allocate memory for it dynamically. For e.g

```
newcar->model = malloc(SIZE); /* define SIZE */
```

Secondly, you are passing just normal `struct vehicle` variable to `add_vehicle()` method So whatever changes are done with `v` in `add_vehicle()` won't affect in `main()` method. Instead `pass the address` of `struct vehicle` variable to `add_vehicle()` method, in that case you no need to return the struct variable as it will be call by reference. for e.g
`main()` method call looks like

```
struct vehicle *head = NULL;
add_vehicle(&head);
```

And definition of `add_vehicle()` looks like

```
void add_vehicle(struct vehicle **v){
    /* some code */
}
```

Here is the sample code you may want

```
void add_vehicle(struct vehicle **v){

        struct vehicle *newcar = malloc(sizeof(struct vehicle));/* no need to type cast the result of malloc */
        scanf("%s", newcar->regnro);
        /* model is pointer member of dtruct, you need to do malloc for it */
        newcar->model = malloc(SIZE)); /*define the size value */
        scanf("%s", newcar->model);

        newcar->next = NULL;
        if((*v) == NULL){ /* first node */
                newcar->next = *v; /* newnode next make it to head node */
                (*v) = newcar; /*update the head node and */
                return;
        }
        else{
                struct vehicle *current = *v;
                while(current->next != NULL){ /* move temp to the end node of list  */
                        current = current->next;
                }
                current->next = newcar;/* add the new_node at last of the list */
        }
}
void print_info(struct vehicle *temp) {
        while(temp) {
                printf("%s %s\n",temp->regnro,temp->model);
                temp= temp->next;
        }
}
int main(void) {
        struct vehicle *head = NULL;            
        add_vehicle(&head); /* pass the address of head */
        print_info(head);
        return 0;
}
```